# Argument 2 passed to Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

I followed installation from [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html#installing-via-composer).

Which is version 3 of the SDK. Basic usage [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html).

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient;
$cdn = new CloudFrontClient(
['version' => 'latest',
 'region'  => 'us-east-1']
);

// Create a new invalidation.
$response = $cdn->create_invalidation('EPYAAAAAAPAA', 'aws-clear-cache' . time(), "/*");
```

According to [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonCloudFront/create_invalidation).

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given,
>   called in
>   /Users/jason/www/aws/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line
>   167 and defined in
>   /Users/jason/www/aws/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line
>   211

UPDATED & WORKING SOLUTION HERE:

```
$config = array(
                'region' => 'us-east-1',
                'version' => '2015-07-27',
                'credentials' => array(
                    'key'    => env('AMAZON_KEY_CLOUDFRONT'),  
                    'secret' => env('AMAZON_SECRET_CLOUDFRONT') 
                )
            );

        $cdn = new CloudFrontClient($config);

        $cache =    array('DistributionId' => env('CLOUDFRONT'),
                    'InvalidationBatch' => array(
                        'CallerReference' => 'none',
                        'Paths' => array(
                            'Quantity' => 1,
                            'Items' => array( 'test' => '/*')
                            )
                        )

            );

        // Create a new invalidation.
        $response = $cdn->createInvalidation($cache);
        var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this. I'm get the same thing and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at what was going on here and apparently you're using an invalid method signature.

First of all, the AWS PHP SDK uses something called "service description models" to get an API interface for the version you specified. In this case that means they are using some meta-programming techniques to provide an interface to what  looks like normal PHP function calls, but the functions are not hard-coded in the SDK. They don't really exist in the sense we generally think of, at least not as regular PHP functions. Some PHP magic is going on underneath.

When you call `$cdn->create_invalidation()` it runs on the `Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient` instance which inherits from `Aws\AwsClient`. Neither of those classes (nor any of their ancestors) actually have a `::create_invalidation()` method implementation. But `AwsClient` does implement the PHP magic method `::__call()`. You can see [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) for the full info on this magic method, but basically when you call any method that doesn't exist on an object, if its class implements `::__call()`, then `::__call()` will be invoked instead.

So now we're inside of `::__call()` (you can see the code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/3.3.8/src/AwsClient.php#L157)) and this method ends up calling `::getCommand()`.  [Inside of `::getCommand()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/3.3.8/src/AwsClient.php#L211) you can see that the method signature requires an array to be passed in (the first argument, `$name`, is the only other method parameter and it's going to have the value `"create_invalidation"` because of the way `::__call()` was implemented above). So that's where the the first problem crops up: you need to pass in an array, not individual strings or timestamps or anything else.

But there's one other thing; the actual method you want to call is not called `create_invalidation`, but `createInvalidation`. There are full API docs for the SDK [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CloudFront.CloudFrontClient.html) - just make sure you pick the right version. For the version I'm looking at, you can find the API docs and method signature for creating invalidations [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cloudfront-2015-07-27.html#createinvalidation).

You can find lots of information about the AWS PHP SDK including links to a User Guide, API Docs, and more, in the project's [GitHub readme](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: I kept running into http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonCloudFront/create_invalidation which is where it came from.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely weird; its probably obsolete and someone didn't realize it's misleading (and wrong) for the current PHP SDK, or I'm sure they would have put a notice somewhere that there was a new location for the latest SDK version's docs. Anyway, if you go to https://aws.amazon.com/ (very bottom of the page, a "PHP on AWS" link under "Resources & Training"), or https://aws.amazon.com/tools/ ("Documentation", under "PHP"), then you'll get linked to the correct page, which you can follow down to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CloudFront.CloudFrontClient.html .

Comment: Why cant you please answer **what to do** ?